# VCL Snippet for changing request.url

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, fastly

I am trying to implement a VCL snippet (for Fastly Varnish implementation), that would replace URL before proxying the request to a service.

Eg.:

`//domain.com/services/user/hello-world` -> `//userservice/hello-world`

To do this, I have written this:

```
      if (req.url.path ~ "^/services/") {
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "/services/(.*?)/", "/");
      }
```

This should be applied just before the backend fetch so that it does not have any impact on caching or other conditions. From the documentation this should be put inside `vcl_pass`. Is that correct? `vcl_fetch` seems to be applied too late for this.

This is edited within Fastly settings as:

[image]

This generates following `vcl_pass` code: https://gist.github.com/knyttl/ae1a3afbc219e311ace3d7d305f9142d

However, it does not work as the target backend receives the full, non-modified url. What am I doing wrong? Is `vcl_pass` correct stage to do this?

Answer (score 2):

### UPDATE

OK, so re-reading through the original poster's question I realised that firstly I had mis-understood their requirements, but then I also noticed their comment on Kailan's answer which also slightly adapted the requirements.

So my understanding is that the requirements are now...

1. Modify the backend depending on the incoming request path.
2. Modify the incoming request path without affecting caching (e.g. the original request path will be what's used in the cache lookup).

For example, if our default backend is `httpbin.org` and the incoming request is to `/services/users` then we want the backend to change to another backend (we'll say `bbc.co.uk`).

But we also want the path to change from `/services/user/` to `/`, while the response from the `bbc.co.uk` backend to be cached under the original request path of `/services/users`/.

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates this:
https://fiddle.fastlydemo.net/fiddle/e337b8f5

> Note: the reason you can't set a string to `req.backend` is because it needs to be assigned a specific [`BACKEND` type](https://developer.fastly.com/reference/vcl/types/backend/).

In case the fiddle link stops working, the code was as follows...

#### vcl_recv

```
if (req.url.path ~ "^/services/user/" ) {
  // pretend www.bbc.co.uk is the correct backend for handling a 'user' request
  set req.backend = F_origin_1;
}
```

> Note: backends are assigned to incrementing variables `F_origin_0`, `F_origin_1` etc. So in my fiddle example `F_origin_0` is httpbin.org while `F_origin_1` is bbc.co.uk

#### vcl_miss

```
if (req.url.path ~ "^/services/.*") {
  set bereq.url = "/";
}
```

### MY ORIGINAL ANSWER

Kailan's answer is correct and should be marked as such, but for completeness I'm going to flesh it out a bit more so the original poster has a clearer conceptual understanding of what's happening...

An incoming request to Varnish is turned into a `req` object that is passed through various states/subroutines (e.g. `vcl_recv` == request received, `vcl_deliver` == request has been processed and a response is ready to be sent back to the client, etc).

Your conditional logic should be added to the `vcl_recv` subroutine as that is the first 'state' for the incoming request, and so is the earliest point at which you can *modify* the request.

The flow of the request object through Varnish can be controlled using the `return(<state>)` directive, which indicates what state to move to next. Varnish has a default behaviour which means you don't *need* to explicitly call `return` at the end of each available subroutine (one will be called for you that will move your request onto the next logical state/subroutine) so your decision to explicitly change the default request flow using `return` will depend on what you're trying to do (in your case you don't need to worry about this).

A typical/default request flow would have the request object move from `vcl_recv` to `vcl_hash` so Varnish can generate a 'lookup' key (which is used to lookup a previously cached version of the request), then depending on if a cached version of the request was found the request will move to either `vcl_miss` (no cached version found) or `vcl_hit` (a cached version was found).

If there was no cached content, then after `vcl_miss` a request will be made to your backend/origin server and the response from the backend will be provided to `vcl_fetch` as a `beresp` object. Finally, the response is passed onto `vcl_deliver` where you can modify the response before it's sent back to the client.

The request (`req`) object is passed through all of these states/subroutines, meaning you can access it at any point during the overall request flow.

If you need more guidance regarding the various VCL subroutines (why they exist, and what you can modify within each of them), then Fastly have them all documented here (along with a nice 'request flow' diagram): https://developer.fastly.com/learning/vcl/using/

Comment: @Vojtěch I've hopefully addressed your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If you modify the path in `recv`, this will be taken into account in the `hash` subroutine meaning that caching will not be affected.

See your example demonstrated in this Fiddle: https://fiddle.fastlydemo.net/fiddle/53bf8ab6

`vcl_pass` will only run if you return `pass` from the recv, miss, or hit subroutines as documented here: https://developer.fastly.com/reference/vcl/subroutines/pass/

Comment: This works with one issue. We have several backends and the backends use request conditions to be matched (see https://gist.github.com/knyttl/b5bbe25a7ed8e8c69a67e9089399ae92). Using this script in RECV replaces the path too soon and so make the request condition to not work :/

Comment: Something like `req.backend = regsub(req.url, "/services/(.*?)/", "F_$1")` would help, but it says `regsub does not return backend`.